C# Reqnroll test - BeforeTestRun hook not firing correctly
I've got a C# framework using Playwright.NET and Reqnroll (formerly SpecFlow).
I've moved common steps across multiple projects into a separate project within the same solution to enable easy reuse.
I've referenced the binding assembly in the reqnroll.json file and the tests run fine.
All projects have the Reqnroll.NUnit NuGet package installed. I'd like to remove the package from all but the shared project - the dependency should mean that the other projects get the package from my shared project.
I've been able to do this with other packages, like Playwright - that's only installed in the shared project and the other projects all get at it via the project dependencies.
But when I remove Reqnroll.NUnit, code I have in a [BeforeTestRun] hook does not run. [BeforeScenario] does but I need [BeforeTestRun] too. If I re-add the package to the project then [BeforeTestRun] works as normal. But the moment I remove it (keeping it in the shared project) then [BeforeTestRun] gets skipped.
Any idea why?
